# Adding Shortcode Values to wp_head

Tags: shortcode, wp-head

I'm trying to create a shortcode with attributes which then places the  values in meta tags for SEO purpose. I know there a some plugins for this use, but I want a simple and reusable/extendable meta tags.

So far I've this piece of PHP code.
The is saved in shortcodes.php and then included in functions.php.

```
add_shortcode('seo_tags', 'seo_tags');
$atts = array();
function seo_tags($atts){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'title' => 'IftinTablets - Android tablets for everyone',
            'description' => '',
            'keywords' => ''
        ), $atts );

    //print_r($atts);
};
```

print_r gives me the desired effect

```
Array ( [title] => Title Value [description] => Description value. [keywords] => keyword1, keyword2 )
```

But I don't get any entries in the header with `wp_head();`

I tried this for `wp_head();` but no errors or desired effect are visible.

```
if(! function_exists('seo_tags')){
    function set_seo(){
        return '
            <meta name="title" content="' . $atts['title']. '" />'
            <meta name="description" content="' . $atts['description']. '" />'
            <meta name="keywords" content="' . $atts['keywords']. '" />';
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'set_seo');
```

What am I doing wrong?? Please someone help with this "easy" issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Use post meta (custom fields), not a shortcode. Shortcodes are embedded in the post content, and that is loaded when the header has been printed already.

Comment: What if I still want to use shortcode for this purpose?
Would you please help with this?

Comment: By the time Wordpress reads your shortcode in the content of the post, the meta tags are already created.  Custom fields are the way to go for you.

Comment: I know that and I've used custom fields for SEO purpose before but it a bit to complicated and one has to follow more steps then using shortcodes. Please help me out, I don't mind the timing.

Comment: Please don't [multipost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896749/adding-shortcode-values-to-wp-head-in-wordpress) the same question.

Comment: You have to accept that this is not what shortcodes are for. They are specifically intended to output something within the body of the post, not in the header, footer, or anywhere else. As others have said, custom fields are your answer in this case.